# full text index can't search content with ',' in it. (mysql 5.7.20, MyISAM)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to using full text index to search content with "," in it.

But I can't, the detail is as below.(mysql 5.7.20, MyISAM)

If I put the "," in my search words, I can't get any result.

```
mysql> select * from tmp;                                                                                             
+-----------------+                                                                                                   
| book_name       |                                                                                                   
+-----------------+                                                                                                   
| hi,there        |                                                                                                   
+-----------------+                                                                                                   
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)                                                                                              
                                                                                                                      
mysql> select book_name from tmp where match(book_name) against('"hi,there"' in boolean mode);                        
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that the Empty set returned. Why?
My setting is as below:

```
                                                                                                                      
mysql> show create table tmp;                                                                                         
show create table tmp;                                                                                                
+-------+--------------+ 
| Table | Create Table |                                                        
+-------+--------------+                                                        
| tmp   | CREATE TABLE `tmp` (                                                                                        
  `book_name` char(32) NOT NULL,                                                                                      
  FULLTEXT KEY `book_name` (`book_name`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */                                              
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |                                                                             
+-------+--------------+                                                        
1 row in set (0.00 sec)                                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
mysql> show variables like '%ngram%';                                                                                 
show variables like '%ngram%';                                                                                        
+------------------+-------+                                                                                          
| Variable_name    | Value |                                                                                          
+------------------+-------+                                                                                          
| ngram_token_size | 2     |                                                                                          
+------------------+-------+                                                                                          
1 row in set (0.01 sec)                                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
mysql> show variables like '%stopword%';                                                                              
show variables like '%stopword%';                                                                                     
+---------------------------------+-------+                                                                           
| Variable_name                   | Value |                                                                           
+---------------------------------+-------+                                                                           
| ft_stopword_file                |       |                                                                           
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword       | ON    |                                                                           
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table |       |                                                                           
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   |       |                                                                           
+---------------------------------+-------+                                                                           
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why ?

Comment: Since the table is MyISAM, you need to look at `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft%';` .  Look especially at the min word len and punctuation characters.

Answer (score 1):

The default full-text index considers words, and commas are not parts of words. From [Natural-language full-text search docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row (document), the number of unique words in the row, the total number of words in the collection, and the number of rows that contain a particular word.

[...]

> The built-in FULLTEXT parser determines where words start and end by looking for certain delimiter characters; for example,   (space), , (comma), and . (period). If words are not separated by delimiters (as in, for example, Chinese), the built-in FULLTEXT parser cannot determine where a word begins or ends. To be able to add words or other indexed terms in such languages to a FULLTEXT index that uses the built-in FULLTEXT parser, you must preprocess them so that they are separated by some arbitrary delimiter. Alternatively, you can create FULLTEXT indexes using the ngram parser plugin (for Chinese, Japanese, or Korean) or the MeCab parser plugin (for Japanese).

and from [Boolean full text search docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".

If your text and query were, for example, "unladen,swallow", so far so good: your query would be searching for the words "unladen" and "swallow" next to each other, ignoring the comma. The reason why you are getting no results is because "hi" is under the word length threshold, and "there" is a [stopword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes) in MyISAM tables, making your query effectively empty. From docs:

> Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for InnoDB search indexes, or four characters for MyISAM. You can control the cutoff by setting a configuration option before creating the index: `innodb_ft_min_token_size` configuration option for InnoDB search indexes, or `ft_min_word_len` for MyISAM.

In other words, you are not really having a problem with a comma, but with the words you are trying to search for. You would get the same results (or rather, the same lack of results) if your data and query were "hi there".

If you change your index into an [ngram index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html), your query will work, as it works on the character level, not word level, and does not treat commas differently. It still uses the same stopword list, but it only excludes tokens that contain a stopword; since your max token size is defined as 2, you could not have `there`, or even `the`, processed as a stopword.

Comment: Thanks, But I have already used the ngram index, see my "show create table tmp" FULLTEXT KEY `book_name` (`book_name`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */. But still I can not search. I have already set the ft_stopword_file  to '' to disable the stopwords.

Comment: In that case, I cannot replicate your results: with `ngram` parser, I find the row. [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/du9TETDrUzQJTFumgFZour/2)

Comment: I have found the reason: Although I created table use "FULLTEXT KEY book_name (book_name)  WITH PARSER ngram", but when I run "show create table ", it shows me that the conent turned to be "FULLTEXT KEY book_name (book_name) /*!50100 WITH PARSER ngram */". Then my case happened. as here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/du9TETDrUzQJTFumgFZour/3 Why?

Comment: I must say I don't know then. For some reason, that is how MySQL shows the column with a ngram parser; the one without a ngram parser shows without that bit. So if you show create table and then run the resulting code, you get a table with a different schema. Weird.